# How to pass query parameters to another component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Relatively new to React, and especially to Routing (with any framework) so please forgive me if this is a simple fix.

I'm trying to route to another React component upon the click of a button on the parent/other component. The buttons represent Room numbers, and I want to pass the data of what room number I clicked to another component that will use that information to launch a query.

I'm having difficulty with passing data to the component, and then from there launching the query. I can detect what button is being pressed.

How can I fix this? Would love any pointers, and above all thank you for your time.

Comment: Does console.log(props.match.params.id) in 'RoomTiles' component comes up in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `history.push` should push the `id` as a URL param. Not as a query param.

```
this.props.history.push(`/RoomTiles/${this.buttonClicked}`);
```

And int `RoomTiles` component, you could use `useParams` to read the param.

```
const RoomTiles = (props) => {
  let { roomId } = useParams();
  return <div>Now in {roomId}</div>;
}
```

Documentation of `useParams` here:

> https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: Hey, just try with a simple `Component` instead of passing it via a `render` function.
`<Route path="/RoomTiles/:id" component={RoomTiles} /> `.

Comment: Yes. you can fetch with `fetch("localhost:5000/ByRoom?roomNo="+roomID)`. This way is passing the `roomNo` as a query parameter. 
Another way is passing via URL parameter. Which would look like `fetch("localhost:5000/ByRoom/"+roomID)`.

The server on the other side should read based on how you pass. Hope you got the difference between query parameter and URL parameter.

Comment: @panditmonium - Request to upvote  and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: hey Vasanth, sounds good! Thanks for your help, I will try it out. I have marked it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your route definition, you are expecting `id` as a path parameter, but in the `handleClick` code you are defining it as a query parameter. So you need to change your path generation logic as below.

```
this.props.history.push("/RoomTiles/" + this.buttonClicked);
```

---

**Updated**

Since you are not passing any custom props from the `App.js` to the `RoomTiles` component, you can simply define the `Route` as follows.

```
<Route path="/RoomTiles/:id" component={RoomTiles}/>
```

Comment: hello Udith, thank you for your response. I was wondering if I should change anything in my App.js component in regards to Routing to /RoomTiles after making the change as you suggested?

Comment: Yes. The route should be defined as follows.
`<Route path="/RoomTiles/:id" component={RoomTiles}/>`